# Show form error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an HTML form in my Rails view

```
<form id="download_form" action="download">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username"> <br/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit_download_form" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In Rails controller, if the length of `username` is greater than 10, I'd like the controller to return to the same page, and notice the user via `<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>` that the length can't be more than 10. How can I do it?

By the way, `username` is **not** an attribute in any model. It's just a field in this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the length of `username` by method `length`:

```
if params[:username].length > 10
  @notice = "the length can't be more than 10"
  render 'download'
end
```

Then in your view you can use `@notice`:

```
<p id="notice"><%= @notice %></p>
```